# Can VPAID tags also accept pure VAST traffic?

Tags: vast

If VPAID is layered onto a VAST tag, can that tag still receive pure VAST traffic?

I'm asking because some ad servers' reporting clearly shows VPAID tags also get pure VAST traffic. I wonder if it's a mistake on their part or not.

Comment: Could you supply a sample?
VPAID is part of the VAST Standard and "nothing but" a different type of media file. Every VPAID media file is delivered via VAST XML, but some player technology may not be able to run that type of media file.

Comment: The XML I refer looks like VPAID for all intents and purposes. But the ad server reports getting various pure VAST ads from it.

Comment: There is no VPAID-XML! VPAID is a spec / standard resp. a type of media implemented in various languages like JavaScript or ActionScript. You get VAST-XML (of course) which might contain a MediaFile with the type VPAID ad.

Comment: I realize that. I just meant the XML looks like <MediaFile apiFramework="VPAID" type="application/javascript">something.js</MediaFile>. So can it also accept pure VAST traffic?

Comment: As a js player can load, read & execute VAST, a VPAID js implementation can also load, read & execute VAST - which is obvious, as it is nothing else than a small player which follows the VPAID specs and runs in another player. (Of course it not has to be like that) I might not get the question?!?

Comment: Btw, there are "some" DSPs & SSPs which are doing exactly that - outsourcing VAST request into a VPAID to push fillrates. As it results in a bad user experience, you should avoid using them!